# Network Interface binding order on Windows 8.1

Tags: windows, networking, command-line-interface, graphical-user-interface

When I query the local interfaces on windows 8 in the command line, I could see the results listed below:

```
C:\> netsh interface show interface

Admin State    State          Type             Interface Name
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
Disabled       Disconnected   Dedicated        Wireless Network Connection
Enabled        Connected      Dedicated        Local Area Connection 5
Enabled        Disconnected   Dedicated        Local Area Connection 3
Enabled        Connected      Dedicated        Local Area Connection 2
```

1. Does the order in the list indicate the network bind order?
2. If so, how could I modify the order of those interfaces. For example, I would like to promote the `Local Area Connection 2` to the top of the list.

Command line command is preferable but GUI steps are also welcome. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why does it matter what order they are listed in?  Tell us what you are actually trying to achieve - there is probably a better way.

Comment: Let's say here is one PC connected to two different networks: `Local Area Connection 5` and `Local Area Connection 2`. I would like to have all the traffic been routed through `Local Area Connection 2` without modifying the route table of the PC.

Comment: This is done by adjusting the metric in the routing table.  Why do you want to avoid that?

Comment: @Grant you are right. I totally forgot about the metric value. Thanks a lot

Comment: I have posted it as an answer so you can accept (and upvote) it.  Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To specify which network adapter to use you need to set the metric value in the routing table.  The order of the list of interfaces has no bearing on which will be used - its all in the routing table.